# How can I document so that the documentation applies to the class member and not the anonymous type?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

Consider the following example.

```
/// \addtogroup api Foo Group
/// @{

/**
 * This class is well-documented.
 */
struct ThreadContext {
    /// Storage for the ThreadInvocation object that contains the function and
    /// arguments for a new thread.
    struct alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) {
        /// This data is glorious.
        char data[CACHE_LINE_SIZE];
    } threadInvocation;
};
/// @}
```

When I run `doxygen` on this, I get the following warning.

```
Doxygen/Main.h:13: warning: Member threadInvocation (variable) of class ThreadContext is not documented.
```

The comment that starts with `Storage for the ...` is supposed to refer to the `threadInvocation` object, but doxygen thinks that it refers to the anonymous `struct` instead.

**How can I tell doxygen that I want the documentation to refer to the `threadInvocation` member?**

Answer (score 3):

After digging through the [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) some more, I discovered that doxygen actually allows documentation of most code almost anywhere. In order to document the `threadInvocation` and avoid the warning about not documenting the anonymous `struct`, I had to write my code like this.

```
/// \addtogroup api Foo Group
/// @{

/**
 * This class is well-documented.
 */
struct ThreadContext {
    /// \var threadInvocation
    /// Storage for the ThreadInvocation object that contains the function and
    /// arguments for a new thread.

    /// \cond SuppressDoxygen
    struct alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) {
        /// This data is glorious.
        char data[CACHE_LINE_SIZE];
    }
    /// \endcond
    threadInvocation;
};
/// @}
```